# Migrate PHP code from MySQL to MS SQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I want to migrate a php/mysql script  to php/sql-server.  The script code isn't mine, I tried to hack it by replacing `mysqli_connect()` with `sqlsrv_connect()`, but it's not working.

How I can migrate the script?

the script source code : https://github.com/fixwa/BlackFramework/tree/master/Lib/xcrud

Below is the database configuration code :

```
/** Database driver; f0ska xCRUD v.1.6.20; 06/2014 */
class Xcrud_db
{
    private static $_instance = array();
    private $connect;
    public $result;
    private $dbhost;
    private $dbuser;
    private $dbpass;
    private $dbname;
    private $dbencoding;
    private $magic_quotes;

    public static function get_instance($params = false)
    {
        if (is_array($params))
        {
            list($dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $dbhost, $dbencoding) = $params;
            $instance_name = sha1($dbuser . $dbpass . $dbname . $dbhost . $dbencoding);
        }
        else
        {
            $instance_name = 'db_instance_default';
        }
        if (!isset(self::$_instance[$instance_name]) or null === self::$_instance[$instance_name])
        {
            if (!is_array($params))
            {
                $dbuser = Xcrud_config::$dbuser;
                $dbpass = Xcrud_config::$dbpass;
                $dbname = Xcrud_config::$dbname;
                $dbhost = Xcrud_config::$dbhost;
                $dbencoding = Xcrud_config::$dbencoding;
            }
            self::$_instance[$instance_name] = new self($dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $dbhost, $dbencoding);
        }
        return self::$_instance[$instance_name];
    }
    private function __construct($dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $dbhost, $dbencoding)
    {
        $this->magic_quotes = get_magic_quotes_runtime();
        if (strpos($dbhost, ':') !== false)
        {
            list($host, $port) = explode(':', $dbhost, 2);
            preg_match('/^([0-9]*)([^0-9]*.*)$/', $port, $socks);
            $this->connect = mysqli_connect($host, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $socks[1] ? $socks[1] : null, $socks[2] ? $socks[2] : null);
        }
        else
            $this->connect = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
        if (!$this->connect)
            $this->error('Connection error. Can not connect to database');
        $this->connect->set_charset($dbencoding);
        if ($this->connect->error)
            $this->error($this->connect->error);
        if (Xcrud_config::$db_time_zone)
            $this->connect->query('SET time_zone = \'' . Xcrud_config::$db_time_zone . '\'');
    }
    public function query($query = '')
    {
        $this->result = $this->connect->query($query, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
        //echo '<pre>' . $query . '</pre>';
        if ($this->connect->error)
            $this->error($this->connect->error . '<pre>' . $query . '</pre>');
        return $this->connect->affected_rows;
    }
    public function insert_id()
    {
        return $this->connect->insert_id;
    }
    public function result()
    {
        $out = array();
        if ($this->result)
        {
            while ($obj = $this->result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $out[] = $obj;
            }
            $this->result->free();
        }
        return $out;
    }
    public function row()
    {
        $obj = $this->result->fetch_assoc();
        $this->result->free();
        return $obj;
    }
    public function escape($val, $not_qu = false, $type = false, $null = false, $bit = false)
    {
        if ($type)
        {
            switch ($type)
            {

                case 'bool':
                    if ($bit)
                    {
                        return (int)$val ? 'b\'1\'' : 'b\'0\'';
                    }
                    return (int)$val ? 1 : ($null ? 'NULL' : 0);
                    break;
                case 'int':
                    $val = preg_replace('/[^0-9\-]/', '', $val);
                    if ($val === '')
                    {
                        if ($null)
                        {
                            return 'NULL';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $val = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    if ($bit)
                    {
                        return 'b\'' . $val . '\'';
                    }
                    return $val;
                    break;
                case 'float':
                    if ($val === '')
                    {
                        if ($null)
                        {
                            return 'NULL';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $val = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    return '\'' . $val . '\'';
                    break;
                default:
                    if (trim($val) == '')
                    {
                        if ($null)
                        {
                            return 'NULL';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return '\'\'';
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ($type == 'point')
                        {
                            $val = preg_replace('[^0-9\.\,\-]', '', $val);
                        }
                        //return '\'' . ($this->magic_quotes ? (string )$val : $this->connect->real_escape_string((string )$val)) . '\'';
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        if ($not_qu)
            return $this->magic_quotes ? (string )$val : $this->connect->real_escape_string((string )$val);
        return '\'' . ($this->magic_quotes ? (string )$val : $this->connect->real_escape_string((string )$val)) . '\'';
    }
    public function escape_like($val, $pattern = array('%', '%'))
    {
        if (is_int($val))
            return '\'' . $pattern[0] . (int)$val . $pattern[1] . '\'';
        if ($val == '')
        {
            return '\'\'';
        }
        else
        {
            return '\'' . $pattern[0] . ($this->magic_quotes ? (string )$val : $this->connect->real_escape_string((string )$val)) .
                $pattern[1] . '\'';
        }
    }
    private function error($text = 'Error!')
    {
        exit('<div class="xcrud-error" style="position:relative;line-height:1.25;padding:15px;color:#BA0303;margin:10px;border:1px solid #BA0303;border-radius:4px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;background:#FFB5B5;box-shadow:inset 0 0 80px #E58989;">
            <span style="position:absolute;font-size:10px;bottom:3px;right:5px;">xCRUD</span>' . $text . '</div>');
    }
}
```

My hacked code :

> private function __construct($dbname, $dbhost, $dbencoding)
>
> ```
>   {
>         $this->magic_quotes = get_magic_quotes_runtime();
>         if (strpos($dbhost, ':') !== false)
>         {
>             list($host, $port) = explode(':', $dbhost, 2);
>             preg_match('/^([0-9]*)([^0-9]*.*)$/', $port, $socks);
>             $this->connect = sqlsrv_connect($host,$dbname, $socks[1] ? $socks[1] : null, $socks[2] ? $socks[2] : null);
>         }
>         else
>             $this->connect = sqlsrv_connect($dbhost, $dbname);
>         if (!$this->connect)
>             $this->error('Connection error. Can not connect to database');
>         $this->connect->set_charset($dbencoding);
>         if ($this->connect->error)
>             $this->error($this->connect->error);
>         if (Xcrud_config::$db_time_zone)
>             $this->connect->query('SET time_zone = \'' . Xcrud_config::$db_time_zone . '\'');
>
>     }
> ```

In config file :

```
>  // default connection
>     public static $dbname = array( "Database"=>"crud1");

>     >     public static $dbhost = '.\sqlexpress';
```

Comment: Dont use mysqli... Use PDO extension to connect to MS SQL server

Comment: I test sqlsrv_connect() in a php file it work good with sql server express

Comment: I found that in the script developer page : Application uses mysqli for connect and working with mySQL. I don’t use PDO because it is not always available on hosting (in future maybe i do it). Now it’s need some changes in query buildings (eg limits) and changing driver in database class to work with MS SQL . 
In next releases i will try to give you ability to choose between mysqli and pdo driver.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PDO, specially if you hope for a better future for your application or website, but you can still use `sqlsrv_*` functions if you want. Whatever you do, make sure you replace all function and provide the right parameters.

Let's see if you want to use SQLSRV Functions (which I don't recommend but I feel this is what you want); You need to change all `mysqli_*` functions with their `sqlsrv_*` counter part, and again, provide the right parameter in the right form:

### Example

In the constructor, you have:

```
$this->connect = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
```

That should be replaced with:

```
$this->connect = sqlsrv_connect($dbhost, array( 'Database'=>$dbName, 'UID'=>$dbuser, 'PWD'=>$dbpass));
```

You see that `mysqli_connect` was called with 4 parameters (all strings), but `sqlsrv_connect` was called with only 2, (a string and an array).

Comment: I think you didn't understand me well, I have replaced all mysqli_connect instances, but that is not worked, I got many errors like Fatal error: Call to a member function set_charset() on a non-object. My goal is convert this php script to work with SQL SERVER